# How can I format the mercurial "hg log" output easily as parsable JSON?

Tags: mercurial

I would like a command-line example on how to easily use `hg log`, with hg filters, and output it safely to JSON (with an array that contains the files).

Multi platform (windows/unix) would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edit: this answer here works for any hg version. for newer hg versions (3.1+), see the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27225512/2759336)* which is more performant and simpler.

Here is a solid oneliner, as an example.

It uses mercurials `hg log`, and pipes its output to a `python` oneliner. The hg log `template` is configured to output valid python literals. The `python` oneliner converts it to JSON.

```
hg log --date ">2014-10-01" --no-merges --keyword "mantis@1953" --keyword "mantis@1955" --template "[\"{node|short}\",\"{author|user|urlescape}\",\"{date|rfc3339date}\",\"{desc|urlescape}\", [{files % '\"{file}\",'}]]\n" --user marinus --user develop | python -c "import sys,ast,json,urllib; x=[[z[0], urllib.unquote(z[1]).decode('utf8'), z[2], urllib.unquote(z[3]).decode('utf8'), z[4]] for z in [ast.literal_eval(y) for y in sys.stdin.readlines()]]; print(json.dumps(x,indent=2))"
```

The above example is for **unix**, but you can simply replace `\"` for `""`, if you need **windows** compatibility. It you want unformatted JSON, set 'indent' to `None`.

The python code is 2/3 compatible (any up-to-date version), and does not use any external modules.

For more explanation of the used hg commands, see:

```
hg help log
hg help dates
hg help templates
```

The python code uses nested `list comprehensions`, google it for more info.

Answer (score 15):

Mercurial has built-in support for JSON.
You can get log output in JSON format simply by using:

```
hg log -Tjson
```

Filters can be used as usual, and to get the files, you can add the '-v' (verbose) parameter.

Note that this is a relatively new feature (see the [wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GenericTemplatingPlan) for more details), which is probably why it's not clearly documented yet.

It's also possible to get xml output using:

```
hg log -Txml
```

Comment: Is there a list of known formats that have their own name like this? Didn't know about the json output.

Comment: Very useful, thx. Too bad this isn't clearly documented in `hg help log`. On our AIX version we have 2.8.1, and both xml and json are not supported. Our Windows version is 3.0.1. xml works, json does not. Because of those limitations, I'll accept the other answer, but will refer to this answer. +1.

Comment: If I knew this earlier it would have saved me a ton of work!

Comment: It doesn't show `json` in the list of templates but it still works -_-